# What is the best way to format this in React/JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I have a component which is pulling in multiple props to use an a URL which is in turn calling an API for JSON data. The props are collected by a series of select boxes which send the selections as props, and the component then installs these props into an axios.get call like so:

```
axios.get(`/inventory_reporter_api/logs?stage=PRODUCTION&severity=${nextProps.selectedSeverity}&start=${nextProps.startDate}&end=${nextProps.endDate}`)
```

So here is my issue. If any of the props are missing, then the axios API call would not work. For instance, in the example above if I have no nextProps.selectedSeverity the api will return an error. So my question is what is the syntax for the call above to say "If there is a nextProps.selectedSeverity then add "&severity=${nextProps.selectedSeverity}" to the URL but if not don't add it. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Just check if those values exist, and build out the url string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if you have a list of the props:

```js
const names = [
  "Severity",
  "Priority",
  "Importance",
  "Urgency"
];

// ...using it...
const nextProps = {
  selectedSeverity: 7,
  selectedImportance: "high"
};
let url = names
  .filter(name => nextProps["selected" + name] !== undefined)
  .map(name => name.toLowerCase() + "=" + encodeURIComponent(nextProps["selected" + name]))
  .join("&");

console.log(url);
```

The `nextProps["selected" + name] !== undefined` check could be whatever check is appropriate to your data, `"selected" + name in nextProps`, etc.

There are a million spins on that. For instance, rather than string concatenation, an array of arrays (or non-array objects, both work):

```js
const names = [
  ["severity", "selectedSeverity"],
  ["priority", "selectedPriority"],
  ["importance", "selectedImportance"],
  ["Urgency", "selectedUrgency"]
];

const nextProps = {
  selectedSeverity: 7,
  selectedImportance: "high"
};
// ...using it...

let url = names
  .filter(([urlParam, propName]) => nextProps[propName] !== undefined)
  .map(([urlParam, propName]) => urlParam.toLowerCase() + "=" + encodeURIComponent(nextProps[propName]))
  .join("&");

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, T.J.!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// for demo purposes
let nextProps = {
  startDate: '1janv2019',
  endDate: '10janv2019'
}

let url = '/inventory_reporter_api/logs?'
  + [
      { key: 'severity', var: nextProps.selectedSeverity },
      { key: 'start', var: nextProps.startDate },
      { key: 'end', var: nextProps.endDate }
    ]
    .map(o => o.var ? `${o.key}=${o.var}` : '')
    .join('&')

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Thank you Nino I will try this!

Comment: The problem is that it's inputting a "&" in the URL if the nextProps is blank and causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a small utility to build up params object.

```
const buildParams = (input, paramKey, paramValue) => typeof paramValue !== 'undefined' ? { ...input, [paramKey]: paramValue } : input;

let params = { stage: 'PRODUCTION' };
params = buildParams(params, 'severity', nextProps.selectedSeverity);
params = buildParams(params, 'start', nextProps.startDate);
params = buildParams(params, 'end', nextProps.endDate);

axios.get('/inventory_reporter_api/logs', params)
```